# AxiosCRUD in Vue inspect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Im doing my first CRUD with Axios on my Vue to my Laravel Backend.
When i inspect in my browser i get to "api/despesas" but im getting a error(500 error).

```
  created() {
    this.getDespesa();
  },
  methods: {
      async getDespesa() {
    const response = await axios.get("api/despesas").then((response) => {
      this.despesas = response.data.data; 
    });
  },
```

This message appears in the inspect on my browser:

```
>GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/despesas 500 (Internal Server Error)
>Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js?16d0:15)
    at settle (settle.js?db52:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?ec6c:77)
```

If you dont have the answer but you have a good example send too, anything helps. Im new at programming.

Comment: 500 is a server error, which means the problem is not in your Axios or Vue code*, it's in the Laravel backend. Looking in there would be the first step. The browser error is just because the backend sent an error! You should, ideally, handle that case in your Axios function, but it's not the source of your problem. *Unless you sent a request the backend couldn't handle, but the error will still be on the backend

Comment: Also, just a tip for Axios: `.then()` is used when a function returns a Promise, and when that is the case `.then` handles the Promise `resolve` and `.catch()` handles the Promise `reject`. Therefore it is always a good idea to chain a `.catch((error)=>{})` after `.then`. That prevents "unhandled rejection" errors that break your code.

Comment: Thanks Sydney Y, i will look at my backend and use .catch with .then!